# How do I install ibus on Freya?

Tags: ibus

I try since some days to install and make work ibus on Freya but in not work, I want use it for Vietnamese writing. The layout in the default input methods is not good.

Of some one can give me some clues for make it work it will be amazing.

Answer (score 3):

Support for ibus on elementary is not yet complete, but you can still use it with some inconsistencies I just tested it and the only problem was the indicator on wingpanel that didn't update accordingly when switching between different input methods (not a problem if you are only going to use the Vietnamese layout).

You should have `ibus-unikey` installed, if you don't do it with this command:

`sudo apt-get install ibus-unikey`

Now configure ibus through `ibus-setup`. To do this, run the command on a terminal and go to the `input method` tab.

Check the box beside "Customize active input methods"

[image]

Then click the menu below, scroll all the way to the bottom, and select Vietnamese > Unikey.

[image]

Finally click on the add button and make sure you left Unikey as the active input method, then close the window.

[image]

Now you should be able to type using Unikey. To switch layouts use <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> , ( instead of the default  <kbd>Alt + Space</kbd>  ), if you want to change this shortcut then this has to be done from `ibus-setup` on the General tab and not from the shortcuts GUI on Switchboard.

[image]

Comment: Dunno why, but doesn't work for japanese. Can not switch layout. Can you help me? *Ctrl+Space* does nothing.

Comment: Doesn't work for ibus-chewing, either.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to solve the problem-

1. Install your desired input method for **IBus**.
2. Run `ibus-setup` command from **terminal**.
3. Select 'Input method' tab and **Add** your desired input method.
4. Close 'IBus Setup' and run `ibus-daemon -drx` in **terminal**.

It starts IBus daemon but It doesn't show IBus on the panel, it brings up the input method popup and let us choose our desired input method.

If you want IBus to automatically start with the system, then go to **Settings** > **Applications** > **Startup** and add `ibus-daemon -drx` as a custom command.