# how to use iBus in elementary OS 0.4.1?

Tags: ibus

I want to type Bangla. I've downloaded iBus-Avro and added it on iBus input method but current keyboard configuration uses the same old one not iBus.

Is iBus broken on 0.4.1 ??

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. Try command below or follow this [instruction](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/5313/13847).

> Run `ibus-daemon -drx` in terminal.
>  
>   If you want IBus to automatically start with the system, then go to **Settings >
>   Applications > Startup** and add `ibus-daemon -drx` as a custom
>   command.