# ibus (Avro) is not working in elementary OS Loki

Tags: ibus

ibus is not working in elementary OS Loki though installed and setup as required. Even if the the input changed from English to Avro (a Bengali ibus input) except few applications(Eg. Plume Creator), most of the application is not supporting writing with Avro, instead it is continuing writing in English.

ibus Avro setup instruction
https://github.com/sarim/ibus-avro/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you already installed iBus Avro now you need to change **Input Method Configuration** only.

1. Open Terminal and type

   ```
   sudo im-config
   ```
2. Select **Ok** then **Yes**
3. Select `Ibus` as input method for the system
4. Click **Ok** and **Ok** for the next windows. Then restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and [this anwser](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/5313/13847) worked for me:

> Run `ibus-daemon -drx` in terminal.
>   If you want IBus to automatically start with the system,
>   then go to **Settings > Applications > Startup**
>   and add `ibus-daemon -drx` as a custom command.

Comment: This didn't help, didn't change anything.

Comment: This didn't help for me

Answer (score 0):

Add these 3 lines at the end of `~/.profile` file. Then logout and login again. Ibus-Avro should work

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

You should add them to `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bashrc` file, since `~/.profile` is sourced during graphical login.