# How to start ibus daemon on login in elementaryOS Odin?

Tags: ibus

I have added a few input methods in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Input Methods. After that, I would expect the iBus daemon to be auto-started upon boot or login, however I still need to manually start it. I've been doing so via the button in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Input Methods, but there should be a better way?

I found another answer (https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/5313/15156) which mentioned adding `ibus-daemon -drx` as a custom command in Settings > Applications > Startup. Is this still the best solution in Odin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Applications/start (my os isn't in english but this is the middle button),click add and write in personalised command ibus-daemon (im on odin)[image: ibus-daemon]